# IIS 401 errors getting custom master page css and js

Tags: 2013, javascript, css, custom-masterpage, iis

Environment: 2013 Enterprise, single WFE, full control of environment

I'm building a custom master page for a SP site collection using a very basic setup. It's a simple responsive HTML page using [skelJS](http://skeljs.org/) (supported by skel-panels and my own config.js that lays out their settings) and style sheets for each breakpoint (wide/narrow/mobile/etc). When coding the site in Dreamweaver everything shows up fine, but when I sync it to the masterpage gallery and preview it, 95% of my styles and js don't show up. Using IE dev tools, Fiddler and IIS logs, I've found that the GET calls to all of them except `style.css` return 401 errors.

The site structure is pretty straight-forward:

```
index.html
+ css
  - style.css
  - style-wide.css
  - style-narrow.css
  - etc.
+ js
  - config.js
  - skel.min.js
  - skel-panels.min.js
  - etc.
```

And the links to these files are pretty standard:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-wide.css">
etc.
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
etc.
```

Permissions are all the same, and all files are published as major versions. So if the `style.css` is accessible, why are the others throwing 401?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I believe the 401s were because I had a drive mapped to a different spot on the same server but using different credentials. Those credentials should in theory have worked, but I think the problem came from inadvertently using two accounts at the same time. I disconnected the other drive and now things seem to be working a little better. I'm still having issues with it loading the correct styles, but that's a separate question.

Not a very glorious question or answer, but maybe it will help someone out there.